# Modifying values in pandas dataframe with a condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this dataframe;

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['apple','lemon','orange','grape'],
                   'col2':['franceCNTY','italy','greeceCNTY','spain']})
```

I'd like to change the values in col2 with this rule;
if the value contains CNTY, then leave it as it is
else set the value to be Nan.

So, the final dataframe will contain the below values;

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['apple','lemon','orange','grape'],
                   'col2':['franceCNTY',np.nan,'greeceCNTY',np.nan]})
```

How can I change these values? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest is to use `str.contains` with `loc`:

```
df.loc[~df.col2.str.contains('CNTY'),'col2'] = np.nan

>>> df
     col1        col2
0   apple  franceCNTY
1   lemon         NaN
2  orange  greeceCNTY
3   grape         NaN
```

Comment: thanks a lot, this works perfect. the first thing that came to my mind was to use iteration in order to go through all the values and change them accordingly. as I am new to python, I'd be grateful if you can give me a hint on how we decide when to use iteration? e.g in this example why didn't you use for loop to iterate all the values in that column?@jpp

Comment: Whenever possible, when working with pandas dataframes, it's better to avoid iteration. There are some cases where it might be more effective (including many cases with string methods), and sometimes, the use of `apply`, which is essentially iterative, can't be avoided. But `pandas` is full of nice vectorized methods which make it easy to avoid iteration for many tasks

Answer (score 0):

Quick Introduction to pandas [tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/mlcc/intro_to_pandas.ipynb?utm_source=mlcc&utm_campaign=colab-external&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=pandas-colab&hl=en)

```
df2['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda name: np.nan if 'CNTY' in name else name)

print(df2)
col1   col2
0   apple    NaN
1   lemon  italy
2  orange    NaN
3   grape  spain
```

Comment: This isn't recommended as `apply` + `lambda` is an inefficient Python-level row-wise loop.

Comment: @jpp Thanks for telling this, Can you share some resource explaining the `apply - lambda`'s  inefficiency.

Answer (score 0):

#### [`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html)

You can use `where` in-place or not in-place:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].where(df['col2'].str.contains('CNTY'))

print(df)

     col1        col2
0   apple  franceCNTY
1   lemon         NaN
2  orange  greeceCNTY
3   grape         NaN

# in place version
df['col2'].where(df['col2'].str.contains('CNTY'), inplace=True)
```